How to deploy Java source artifacts to GCP Artifact Registry?
I work on a Java library. Sources are managed as a Maven multimodule project.
The build process (essentially mvn deploy) is executed by a GCP's CloudBuild.
The project's pom.xml is configured to publish built artifacts to GCP's Artifact Registry.
Everything works with this setup, .jars with compiled code are correctly deployed to GCP's Artifact Registry.
I would now like to add the source jars to Artifact Registry along with the usual jars. In this way, a developer using my library can download the source jar and check the code. This is common is several IDEs, as it happens for instance in IntelliJ Idea.
And here's the problem! Cloudbuild runs Maven that correctly builds and attaches source jars, but somehow they are not uploaded to Artifact Registry even if the build completes successfully.
Do you know how to solve that?

Take a look at this documentation. Make sure that the target repository exists in Artifact Registry and you also have the appropriate role. Also, see Configuring a Java build.

thx @Marra, the problem is about source jars. Usual jars with compiled code are transferred to ArtifactRepository as expected.
